# Array and pointer adress in C

Tags: c

I was asked to write a function that returns the average value of numbers in an array. It's pretty straight forward:

```
int array_sum(int seq[], int len) {
int sum = 0;
for (int i = 0; i < len; ++i) {
sum += seq[i];}
return sum;}

float array_avg(int seq[], int len) {
int sum = number_sum(seq,len);
return sum/len;}
```

But now I have to rewrite it so that seq is a pointer:

```
int array_sum(int *seq, int len) {   <--- This function is working properly
int sum =0;
for(int *p = seq; p < len+seq; ++p)
{sum += *p;}
return sum;}  

float seq_avg(int *seq, int len) {
int sum = number_sum(*seq,len);  <---- THIS LINE CAUSES AN ERROR
return sum/len;}
```

I have tried

-number_sum(*seq,len);

-number_sum(&seq,len);

but none of them seem to work. How to make it work?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should only pass the pointer, and not dereference it: `*seq` is an `int` while `seq` is an `int*`.

```
float seq_avg(int *seq, int len) {
    int sum = number_sum(seq, len);
    return sum/len;}
```

Also, your method is named `array_sum`, not `number_sum`, what is the exact error you get? It can be called the same way as your first methods, and the indexing can be done in the same way too with `seq[i]`.

copy paste it and check if it works:

```
int array_sum(int* seq, int len)
{
  int sum = 0;
  for (int i = 0; i < len; i++) {
    sum += seq[i];
  }
  return sum;
}

float array_avg(int* seq, int len) 
{
  int sum = array_sum(seq, len);
  return sum / len;
}
```

Comment: mumber_sum(seq, len) works! yeah I did mess up the method name in my question. Thanks for you answer!

Comment: it is common to mess up names:), glad it helped, check it as answer please:D

Answer (score 2):

This

```
int array_sum(int seq[], int len)
```

and this

```
int array_sum(int * seq, int len)
```

are equivalent.

In both cases `seq` is a pointer to `int`.

Concluding from this both implementations of the function are used, will say called the same way.

```
int array_sum(int * seq, size_t len)
{
  int sum = 0;
  for (size_t i = 0; i < len; ++i) 
  {
    sum += seq[i];
  }
  return sum;
}

float array_avg(int * seq, size_t len) 
{
  int sum = array_sum(seq, len);
  return (float) sum / len; /* By casting sum to float you make 
                               sure not an integer division is performed. */
}
```

Call it like this:

```
int main(void)
{
  int a[] = {0, 3, 2, 4, 1};
  float avg = array_avg(a, sizeof a / sizeof a[0]);
  return 0;
}
```